# Why are typescript files showing these errors in my every react-native project in vscode?

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, tsx, react-tsx

I have been working on some react-native projects in Typescript JSX, and the code was working completely fine until a few days ago but when I pushed it to GitHub and made some pull requests to make the changes it showed me these errors, not just this project but every project that I have in my pc that has a .tsx file is showing these errors in VSCode

These are the errors:
[image]

Comment: Indent your code, bro, damn.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the relevant code? Also, state which version of VS Code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like syntax errors on `< /` in the closing tags. Remove the spaces and make it `</Text>` etc.

Edit: if this happens in every project, you should check if you're using some auto-formatting that's not correctly configured for TSX, mistakes the JSX tags for `<` `>` operators and inserts spaces around them.